# In certain rows get values form one column and spread it to another columns

Tags: python, pandas

There is a following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(9,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.loc[5:7,'A']=123
```

[image: df]

In every row where there is 123 in column 'A', I want 'C' and 'D' column values to be equal to 'B'.

Desirable output:

[image: desirable]

I tried:

```
df.loc[df['A']==123].assign(**(df.C=df.B,df.D=df.B ))
```

Which returned SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set column `B` to list of columns in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(9,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.loc[5:7,'A']=123

df.loc[df['A']==123, ['C','D']] = df.B
print (df)
     A    B    C    D
0  864  392  323  630
1  707   91  637  643
2  583  952  157  560
3  160  920  970  777
4  691  139   55  626
5  123  195  195  195
6  123  156  156  156
7  123  980  980  980
8   79  325  458  841
```

Your solution should be changed with different syntax - removed `**` and for reassign columns is removed `df.`:

```
df.loc[df['A']==123] = df.assign(C=df.B,D=df.B)
```